# How to link libraries for python module?

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I am trying to install a python module called tables, which depends on HDF5. I have installed HDF5 using pkgsrc, so the libraries and headers are in /usr/pkg/lib and /usr/pkg/include, respectively. This is on a Mac (OS 10.9.4).

I am able to install the tables module using pip only if I first export HDF5_DIR=/usr/pkg. That's not a problem in and of itself, but after pip says it has successfully installed tables, I still can't import the module and the error message seems to indicate that it can't find a library related to HDF5. Please see the error message below. I'm guessing that the hint in the error is `2): Symbol not found: _H5E_CALLBACK_g`

```
In [1]: import tables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-389ecae14f10> in <module>()
----> 1 import tables

/Users/gregory/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/__init__.py in <module>()
     80 
     81 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension
---> 82 from tables.utilsextension import (
     83     get_pytables_version, get_hdf5_version, blosc_compressor_list,
     84     blosc_compcode_to_compname_ as blosc_compcode_to_compname,

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gregory/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so, 2): Symbol not found: _H5E_CALLBACK_g
  Referenced from: /Users/gregory/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/gregory/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so
```